# Connect to Transbase via Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, transbase

I'm currently looking for the most convenient way to connect to a Transbase DB with Spring Boot.
Is it even possible with Spring JDBC? Do I need additional drivers? And what do I need to configure in my application.properties? I couldn't make it work by now.

Already tried to search for someone who has done this before but Transbase does not seem to be very popular, so without success.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to add additional Transbase jdbc driver to your classpath.

And you can configure your your spring boot with following properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: transbase.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:<your jdbc url>
spring.datasource.username: <username>
spring.datasource.password: <password>
```

And if you got any database specific additional properties, set it like this

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.<your datasource specific property key> : <value>
```